# Highchart offline export trying to loading libs from online cdn and errors out

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using offline export for high chart and have included following scripts:

```
 <script src="Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/highcharts-more.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/highcharts/5.0.14/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

I have also included following options on my java script.

```
Highcharts.getSVG = function (charts, options, callback) {
        var svgArr = [],
            top = 0,
            width = 0,
            addSVG = function (svgres) {
                // Grab width/height from exported chart
                var svgWidth = +svgres.match(
                    /^<svg[^>]*width\s*=\s*\"?(\d+)\"?[^>]*>/
                )[1],
                    svgHeight = +svgres.match(
                        /^<svg[^>]*height\s*=\s*\"?(\d+)\"?[^>]*>/
                    )[1],
                    // Offset the position of this chart in the final SVG
                    svg = svgres.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
                svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');
                top += svgHeight;
                width = Math.max(width, svgWidth);
                svgArr.push(svg);
            },
            exportChart = function (i) {
                if (i === charts.length) {
                    return callback('<svg height="' + top + '" width="' + width +
                        '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>');
                }
                charts[i].getSVGForLocalExport(options, {}, function () {
                    console.log("Failed to get SVG");
                }, function (svg) {
                    addSVG(svg);
                    return exportChart(i + 1); // Export next only when this SVG is received
                });
            };
        exportChart(0);
    };

    /**
     * Create a global exportCharts method that takes an array of charts as an argument,
     * and exporting options as the second argument
     */
    Highcharts.exportCharts = function (charts, options) {
        options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

        // Get SVG asynchronously and then download the resulting SVG
        Highcharts.getSVG(charts, options, function (svg) {
            Highcharts.downloadSVGLocal(svg, options, function () {
                console.log("Failed to export on client side");
            });
        });
    };

    // Set global default options for all charts
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        exporting: {
            fallbackToExportServer: false // Ensure the export happens on the client side or not at all
        }
    });
```

Now I have deployed the code to production and when I click on download png , getting a error on console ,

> Error loading script https://code.highcharts.com/5.0.14/lib/rgbcolor.js

I am not sure why it's trying to get the script from highchart cdn when I have everything on my local directory.

Comment: @Derek, Do you mean in the question tag?

Comment: @Derek, If you are pointing towards the Highcharts.getSVG = function (charts, options, callback) { ..section in question, it's in a separate js file.

Comment: @Derek, My Bad, fixed that..

Comment: Does the problem still occur?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the option libURL to your local path where the additional libs are located.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.libURL?_ga=2.13049847.1116742286.1556551485-573722723.1548845412